# How to escape a semicolon in xsl:param?

Tags: visual-studio, xslt

I'm writing an XSL transform in Visual Studio. It is reporting that the semicolon in the following is an "unexpected token":

```
<xsl:param name="delimiters" select=";#" />
```

Does anyone know how to escape the semicolon? It hasn't shown up on any character lists I've found so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You presumably want the param `delimiters` to have the *string* `;#` as it's value, given that that isn't a valid XPath expression? If so, you need to quote the attribute value:

```
<xsl:param name="delimiters" select="';#'" />
```

Note that the value is now wrapped in single quotes; this causes the attribute value to be interpreted as an XPath expression which returns a string.

Comment: This is also a possible alternative `<xsl:param name="delimeters">;#</xsl:param>`.  This sometimes is more clear in some editors which smoosh together quote and apostrophe together.

Comment: In that case, the value of the variable is actually a Result Tree Fragment containing a single text node, rather than a string. Of course this makes absolutely no difference in most cases, but it's worth noting. http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Result-Tree-Fragments

Comment: @NickFitz: Thanks, I didn't know that. Now that you say it, it is absolutely logical. :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
<xsl:param name="delimiters" select="';#'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following entity (semi-colon is ASCII character 59)...

```
&#59;
```

Answer (score 0):

wallenborn is right. The reason is that a `select` attribute in XSL always expects an XPath expression. If you want to put a string literal there, you need to quote it.