# What is the escape character for semi-coloon(;) in xslt

Tags: xslt, tags, escaping

I can't seem figure out the escape character for semi-colon(;) in XSLT.
I'm trying to put this line in my head tag

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16">
```

but the semi-colon (`;`) after the HTML is causing me problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape a semicolon in xsl:param?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709162/how-to-escape-a-semicolon-in-xslparam)

Comment: If it's causing you problems, why not tell us what the problems are? Semicolons do not need to be escaped in any context that comes to mind. I suspect the real problem is that in XML, the start tag needs a corresponding end tag or needs to auto close using "/>".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hello world in C with no semi-colons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754493/hello-world-in-c-with-no-semi-colons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `xsl:output` instead:

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes" />
```